# Firebase Crashlytics not showing crash report in console dashboard swift

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-console

I have setup all these steps and bundel id on Firesbase Dashboard and tried crash many times but not getting any report.

1. **pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.2'
   pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.9.3'**
2. In Build phase added run Script : **"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"**
3. Debug Inforation Format : **DWARF with dSYM File**
4. running in simulator with following steps

   - (IBAction)crashButtonTapped:(id)sender {
     [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash];
     }
   - Click play_arrow Build and then run the current scheme in Xcode to build your app on a device or simulator.
   - Click stop Stop running the scheme or action in Xcode to close the initial instance of your app. This initial instance includes a debugger that interferes with Crashlytics.
   - Open your app again from the simulator or device.
     Touch Crash to crash the app.

Comment: Are you able to share your app's bundle ID so I can take a closer look?

Comment: @ Alexizamerican com.Salman.Test

Comment: Thanks. It looks like crashes are coming through for your app now. Are you seeing them on your end?

Comment: @Alexizamerican Yes it's showing now in Event Trends graph but in Dashboard display count of Crashes is 0 and In crash reporting its displaying but not recent crashes with Crashes uploaded successfully.

Comment: Yeah, there's currently a delay between Firebase analytics and crashes on Crashlytics. Crashes on Crashlytics should appear almost immediately.

Comment: Ok, thanks, @Alexizamerican it's now showing after some delay.

Comment: Great, Salman. I'm glad it's showing up!

Comment: @Alexizamerican crash report is uploaded on firebase on dash board i am getting  [ Test 4506976340 + 65620 ] symbolic form it is not showing my method name.

Comment: @Alexizamerican one more issue I am getting is I am doing force crash on my app crash report is uploaded but my crashes are showing only 4 of the previous date in Crashlytics section but updating correctly in crash reporting section.

Comment: There are a couple of things to investigate here and I recommend reaching out to Firebase support so the team can take a closer look.

Comment: @Alexizamerican ok thank you.

Answer (score 13):

I took the same steps as you and thought I had an issue until I realized there's a delay for the crashes to show up on the console. In my case it took about 40 minutes to appear.

Here's a blog [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html) about it.

Comment: But according to their documentation about [force a crash](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash), it will appear within 5 minutes...

Comment: Nope, still nothing after a 24 hours. Followed all the same infinite wisdom.

Comment: Any updates. How long it will take to show the crashed report

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Check run script only when installing

Answer (score 1):

I did everything on stack overflow; my upload was successful, but nothing showed up. After trying to figure out the solution, I tried this, and it worked for me as well as for some other people facing the same issue... might help others who end up here.

I posted it in issues section. Check it out https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/413

One thing that I did was to move my test crash

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
```

to the first view controller (e.g., WelcomeViewController),then after the crash I closed and opened my app again. Then just waited for sometime and it appeared.

Before doing all of that my test crash was within a view controller, which was part of a tabBarController as it wasn't the top most view controller. Maybe that's what caused the issue. After my first crash appeared on the firebase console then my other crashes started appearing.

Comment: This solution did the trick for me. It seems it does not send a crash report while connected to Xcode or in debug mode. Opened the app, closed it then opened again, viola, I found my forced crash there on dashboard

Comment: I had a same problems, and I solved it. call Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)

Answer (score 0):

Check your app bundle identifier in app eg. bundle identifier is `abc_app`, the go to the Firebase app console project overView - > project settings and then Your App section select your app and check that the bundle identifier in the app and bundle identifier in the Firebase app. Both should be the same!