# Crashlytics is not sending Crash report from iPhone or Real Deivce

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics, crash-reports

I followed exactly the way described in documentation. But it's not working. Below is the log I see on the console.

```
5.9.0 - [Firebase/Crash][I-CRA100003] Crashes uploaded successfully, but there was an error deserializing the response
```

I'm using below code snippet to crash the app.

```
@IBAction func crashButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
}

let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 50, width: 100, height: 30)
button.setTitle("Crash", for: [])
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector( self.crashButtonTapped(_:) ), for: .touchUpInside)
view.addSubview(button)
```

**Edit:**

I'm testing on simulator and below are few screenshots appeared after updating pods (crashlytics and Fabric) on Firebase dashboard.

[image]

[image]

How to upload dSYMs?

Comment: Did you add Run Script Build Phase to the project?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074877/firebase-crashlytics-not-showing-crash-report-in-console-dashboard-swift

Comment: are you testing it on simulator?

Comment: I added run script, and followed stackoverflow.com/questions/48074877. And yes I'm testing on simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve my issue after uploading the dSYM file. Here is how I retrieved it on the project. I run my on debug mode and simulator.

1. First you have to Archive 
   (Select "Generic iOS Device" or your real device) the project. Then Product --> Archive menu will appear.

After successful archive you will be able to see "YourAppName.app"

2. On your Xcode project structure, Right click on "YourAppName.app" (it's under Products --> YourAppName.app) and "Show in finder".

There is file called "YourAppName.app.dSYM" and zip this file and upload it to the firebase. Everything worked fine. I noticed I had to upload YourAppName.app.dSYM again and again on debug mode when rebuild the app. Please let me know if anyone found a solution to that.

Comment: any solution tothis?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Target -> Build Settings -> Debug Information Format -> DWARF with dSYM File

Comment: Try the add dsyms file in Firebase

Comment: How to get that? Remember I'm running this on simulator and not connected to iTunesConnect.

Comment: in xcode -> window -> orgnizer

or xcode - > product -> Archive

you see Archives window

1 Select any Archives of your app Right click on it Then select show in finder

2 you see aapname.xcarchive file Right click on it and select show package contents

3 you see dSYMs folder open it and get .dSYM file

Comment: Hi Taimoor, Thanks for the help. I could not retrieve or did not see any archives When I opened Organizer nor right click anywhere. Please find below how I resolved the issue.

Comment: Did You Create Archive ?
Product -> Archive .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185706/discussion-between-happycoder-and-taimoor-suleman).

Answer (score 0):

read the troubleshooting part of the below link carefully

https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/test-crash.html#cause-a-test-exception